# How to fix the garbled output on /dev/ttyUSB0 of my depth sensor in shell? (should be clean NMEA 0183)

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, serial-port, nmea

The output of /dev/ttyUSB0 (when using screen) is garbled. I have hooked up a Depth-Sensor to it which ouputs NMEA0183 Sentences via RS232. I am using a RS232 to USB Interface between the Sensor and my Computer.

The Depth Sensor is a Cruzpro ATU120A, the manufacturer gives these informations about the specifics of the serial connection:
"Data Ouput:
NMEA 0183 serial 4800 BAUD, $SDDPT, $SDDBT, $SDMTW"

I have tried all typical Baudrates and other combinations of stopbit/databits/parity. I have also tried gpsd to autodiscover the right combination, but it couldnt.

I am using this command:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 4800 8N1
```

The output is garbled, but I can clearly see the structure of the NMEA-Sentences in the garble.

It looks like this

```
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
[u�}]�������Yww{W���:;+�ڭ����[u�]E�>�����y�����
```

(I added new-lines for clarity, where a sentence ended, I could tell when a sentence started by the timing and the repeating Brackets)

I expect clean lines, that start with $SDDPT, $SDDBT or $SDMTW and end with a CR-LF

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the problem. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So far I am not using any code, so far I am just using shell and screen to look at the output of the sensor. when that works, I can go on and write code.

Comment: Since you seem to be using the correct baudrate, the ground connection is suspect.  Check your wiring.  *"I am using a RS232 to USB Interface"* -- More commonly called a USB-to-RS232 converter/adapter (i.e. the host-side of the module is mentioned first).